# Regexp to match a command line java application execution with args

Tags: java, regex

I'm absolutely not familiar with regexes so better to ask then do something very silly. I have a java application that is to be executed from command line, and it has a pretty nice signature.

```
java applicationName -mode=create -some.nice.arg=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX -another.nice.arg=value2 -third.nice.arg=value3 -again.nice.arg=value4 ... -nth.nice.arg=value_n+1
```

This would be the desired format. Well at least close enough. I'm trying to create a regexp that matches this and would select the argument fields like:

- mode=create
- some.nice.arg=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX
- another.nice.arg=value2
- third.nice.arg=value3
- again.nice.arg=value4
- ...
- nth.nice.arg=value_n+1

I have no problem creating a regexp for IP address for example, but I can't create one that would match this whole stuff. So far my best bet was:

```
\w+[ ]{1}\w+[ ]{1}[-]{1}(\w+[=]{1}\w+){+}
```

Lots of problems. For example \w+ won't match '.' chars but they will be there for sure. Or for another example:
 mode can have one of the following options:

- create
- update
- clear

I'm kinda shot even at the first problem not to mention the second.

Thanks for every help!
 - Joey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to solve this problem is to use a command line interface library, such as [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/). Using these libraries you can define the arguments for your application and the library will validate the input (i.e. your `String[] args`) against this.

Most CLI libraries can handle advanced concepts such as optional arguments, flags, multi-part arguments etc. They can also be used to print a helpful usage message for your users. Check out some [examples here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html).

Once you've used a library such as this to gather the arguments, you can then use a regexp (if necessary) to validate each part separately.

Comment: Awesome solution. thanks for recommending this Commons CLI. works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to create regex for this here is the tip:

`mode=(\\w+)\\s+some.nice.arg=((?:\\w{3}\\.){3}\\w{3}:\\w{4})\\s+another.nice.arg=(\\S+?)\\s+third.nice.arg=(\\S+?)\\s+again.nice.arg=(\\S+?)`

etc, etc.

However better way is to split you line into segments and then process each one:

```
String line = ....;
String[] segments = line.split("\\s+");

for (String segment : segments) {
    String[] parts = segment.split("=");
    String name = parts[0];
    String value = name[1];
    // deal with names and values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could suit your needs to capture the parameters:

```
-([a-zA-Z.-]+)=((?:"[^"]+"|[^ ])+)
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?34t38)